# Freetext search multi-columns in c # (Linq)

Tags: c#, linq, full-text-search, freetext

Is there the possibility by using EF.Functions.FreeText to search on multiple columns?

The function accepts as input parameters: the column in which to perform the search and the string to search for, but in the documentation I cannot find anything that makes me understand if I can execute it in this context FREETEXT ((col1, col2, col3), 'search')

Comment: EF Core 5 does not support this yet - see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10462).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the && Operator to chain them

`_context.Foo.Where(x => EF.Functions.FreeText("Column1", "Search Text") && EF.Functions.FreeText("Column2", "Search Text"));`

If you want to do it dynamically I fear that you have to use `FromSqlRaw`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it does not find any records, while on Sql Server it finds something

Comment: @RiccardoPezzolati Try using `||` instead of `&&`.